# 267main.tsx.8578f314.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: p.getQuestions is not a function at main.tsx.8578f314.js:5:61923

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is  getting showed in console, i have nowhere used this getQuestions.

Thanks in Advance.|

I tried using Vite instead of react same error still/
267main.tsx.8578f314.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: p.getQuestions is not a function     at main.tsx.8578f314.js:5:61923

Comment: Have you used any library code that could include that? What happens if you click the line number in the console?

Comment: It is opening some large code and showing
const u = $t();
        return u && (lt = setInterval(()=>{
            const p = new u
              , b = p.getQuestions()
              , x = p.harvestAnswers();
            _1(x, o.current) && n(x),
            x.length === 0 && !E1(e, b) && (t(b),
            localStorage.setItem("scrapedQuestions", JSON.stringify(b)))
        }
        , 500)),
        ()=>lt && clearInterval(lt)
    }
showing error in this part

Comment: _"I tried using Vite instead of react"_: did you mean you use Vite instead of _create-react-app_?

Comment: Yes, i though first it was some issue with create-react-app then i tried using vite , still same thing my app is working fine but this error is showing in console everytime

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When you click the link and see the "large code", you likely will see a pair of curly brackets in the lower left of that window. What happens if you click them?

Answer (score 1):

i was also getting this error.
check the initiator of main.tsx
for me it was coming through chrome extension
[see the network call for main.tsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9Ci6.png)

So for me own of my extension with that ID was causing extension.
I removed that anyway unwanting extension. working fine now.

[error which I was getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cghH.png)

Comment: Yes,I Did The same and it got resolved..Thank You!!

Answer (score 0):

Removing an unwanted extension solved the issue!

Comment: Which extension? It would be helpful for others to know. Otherwise, please consider deleting your question.